# Ajax.Actionlink output with id attribute

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I'm using the `Ajax.Actionlink` from the MVC framework and everything works fine with my targets and partial views. However I've seen that the html output doesn't add the "id" attribute to the resulting `<a href=""></a>` tag.

Is there any way how I can add it?

Answer (score 7):

Try one of the overloads, like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470546.aspx):

```
public static string ActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Then you can specify the id in the *htmlAttributes* parameter, e.g.

```
new { id = "myIdValue" }
```

Comment: +1: This is also correct, but 5 minutes later... nice example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `new { id = "myId" }` in the object htmlAttributes parameter, available in several of its constructors. Or you can fill it using the `IDictionary<string, string>` htmlAttributes also available in several of its constructors.

Comment: He needs the routeValues parameter. HtmlAttributes would set the id attribute of the anchor tag itself.

Comment: My understanding of his question was that he wanted <a id="myId">a</a>

Comment: I think that's what's being asked for - "add the "id" attribute to the resulting tag"?  This answer sounds correct.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you're looking for the routeValues parameter.

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { id = ID_HERE }, null) %>
```

Comment: -1: This is not correct. This adds a parameter to the route, not an id attribute to the anchor tag (which the OP is asking).